# How to I program an icon in my power app to trigger a click of my camera control?

Tags: powerapps

In my app I have a camera control and a camera icon. I want the user to be able to click on a camera icon so that it triggers the same effect as clicking on the camera control. The OnSelect code for the camera control "Camera1" is the following:

```
Set(
    varName,
    GUID()
);
Collect(
    colImages,
    {
        DisplayName: varName & ".jpg",
        Id: varName & ".jpg",
        Value: Camera1.Photo
    }
);
```

The OnSelect code for Camera1 works perfectly (see first arrow in screenshot), so then I tried pasting the same exact code into the OnSelect of the camera icon (second arrow in screenshot). But whenever the user click's on the camera icon, it takes a blank photo and fails to add it to the attachment list. My app is modeled after this [Reza Dorrani youtube video](https://youtu.be/iW9dpDntKrY). Does anyone know why that code for the camera icon is not working? How can I get this camera icon to behave exactly the way Camera1 does?

[image: Clicking these two items should perform the same thing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be out of luck:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Pictures-Not-Collecting-Displaying-Properly/td-p/329847

Comment: I tried the Select(Camera1) code and it seems to behave exactly as the my original attempt does, unfortunately. That is, it takes a blank photo, or replicates the most recent photo taken by the camera control, without taking a new photo. Any idea why that is? Is it impossible for anything other than the camera control itself to have authorization to use the device's camera?

Comment: Edited the answer. Have you attempted accessing the stream. Depending on how you are using the camera Photo property is always accessing the last taken photo

Comment: I just changed it from Camera1.Photo to Camera1.Stream and the result seemed to be the same, blank white photo :(

Comment: What happens when you use Stream on the Camera control OnSelect function?

Comment: Interesting idea. When I use Camera1.Stream for the camera control and Camera1.Stream for the camera icon, then clicking on either one of those simply takes blank photos. But when I use Camera1.Stream for the camera control and Camera1.Photo for the camera icon, then clicking on camera control takes a blank photo, but clicking immediately after on the camera icon displays that previous attempted image in my gallery. Does that mean we're getting closer to getting the camera icon to take a photo directly?

Comment: I think you may be out of luck. 
Seems this may be by design: 
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Pictures-Not-Collecting-Displaying-Properly/td-p/329847